# Empty response curl trakt api

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get my access token from trakt.tv.
I get the authorization code and, as the documentation says I do:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        $code = $_GET['code'];
        $data = array(
          "code"=>$code, 
          "client_id"=>"my client id",
          "client_secret"=>"my client secret",
          "redirect_uri"=>"my redirect url",
          "grant_type"=>"authorization_code"
        );
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://trakt.tv/oauth/token");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          "Content-Type: application/json"
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($response);
```

However, the response is empty. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what value you are posting to $code ?

Comment: It's the code I get when I authorize the application. Basically I get this code and I need to "exchange" it with the access token. http://docs.trakt.apiary.io/#reference/authentication-oauth/authorize/exchange-code-for-access_token?console=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the request header. Try

```
$header = array("Content-type: application/json",
                "trakt-api-key: yourclientkeyhere",
                "trakt-api-version: 2"

               );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```